# How to define a variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting the error message `$data is undefined` when I try to debug my code by using `var_dump($data);`

[This is my java-script code](https://pastebin.com/EH0WvA30) and the paste bin is my PHP code, there was just too much to put it in one post.

https://pastebin.com/EH0WvA30

However I am not sure what to define it as, or where to define it in my PHP code. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
 function getItinerary (){ 
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/itinerary.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {action: 'LOAD'
    userId: $userId,
    attractionId: $attractionId
    }, //Here put two mode keys and values, userId and attractionId like {userId: '<value here required by your server>',attractionId: '<value here required by your server>'}
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('request successful');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Network or Server error');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: share ur php code

Answer (score 0):

Due to this if condition

```
if(!empty($_POST['userId']) && !empty($_POST['attractionId']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {

}
```

If you don't send useId and attractionId in your ajax request, the condition will return false.

I think that's the reason for not working

Update your ajax code like this

```
 function getItinerary (){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/itinerary.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'LOAD'}, //Here put two mode keys and values, userId and attractionId like {userId: '<value here required by your server>',attractionId: '<value here required by your server>'}
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert('request successful');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Network or Server error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I send it in the ajax request?

Comment: It still says undefined variable

Comment: can be seen above